# Komma in: "das ist wie wenn"?

Tags: punctuation, conjunction, comma

Ich steh gerade auf dem Schlauch.

> Das ist wie wenn man zu viel Bier trinkt.

Kommt in den Satz ein Komma?

Erst wollte ich eins nach dem *ist* setzen, dann nach dem *wie,* dann sahen beide komisch aus und ich habe mich gegen Kommata entschieden.
Stimmt das?

Comment: Da eine Alternative "Das ist, als ob..." ist, würde ich auf "Das ist, als wie..." tippen. Aber ohne Garantie ;)

Comment: Du hast zwei finite Verben. Das riecht nur so nach Komma ;)

Comment: Nicht ganz ernster Vorschlag: „Das ist wie: wenn man zuviel Bier trinkt.“

Comment: Im Marketing setzt man einfach hinter jedes Wort einen Punkt.Im Marketing.  Wirklich. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Man setzt vor *wie wenn* ein Komma. Siehe [§ 74 E1](http://www.duden.de/sites/default/files/downloads/amtliche_Regelungen.pdf).

Comment: +1 für die Quelle. Ich finde das Komma da aber unschön.

Answer (score 11):

§ 74 E1 der Rechtschreibregeln lautet:

> E1: Besteht die Einleitung eines Nebensatzes aus einem Einleitewort und
>   weiteren Wörtern, so gilt:
>
> (1) Man setzt das Komma vor die ganze Wortgruppe:
>
> […] *Sie rannte, wie wenn es um ihr Leben ginge.* […]

Hier wird explizit der gleiche Fall als Beispiel genutzt. Ein Komma vor *wie* (und nur dort) ist also auf jeden Fall richtig.

Weiter geht es mit:

> (2) In einigen Fällen kann der Schreibende zusätzlich ein Komma zwischen
>   den Bestandteilen der Wortgruppe setzen:
>
> *Morgen wird es regnen, angenommen(,) dass der Wetterbericht stimmt. Wir
>   fahren morgen, ausgenommen(,) wenn es regnet. Ich glaube nicht, dass er
>   anruft, geschweige(,) dass er vorbeikommt. Ich glaube nicht, dass er anruft,
>   geschweige denn(,) dass er vorbeikommt. Ich komme morgen, gleichviel(,) ob
>   er es will oder nicht. Ich werde ihnen gegenüber abweisend oder 
>   entgegenkommend sein, je nachdem(,) ob sie hartnäckig oder sachlich sind. Egal(,)
>   welche Farbe sie sich aussucht, sie wird immer gut aussehen.*

Leider schweigen sich die Regeln völlig dazu aus, was diese „einigen Fälle“ auszeichnet. Ich kann nur raten, dass die meisten der jeweils ersten Konjunktionen *(angenommen, ausgenommen, geschweige (denn), gleichviel, egal)* durch einen kurzen Satz ersetzt werden können (z. B. *angenommen* → *wobei angenommen sei).* Das gilt in Deinem Satz auch:

> Das ist, wie [es ist], wenn man zu viel Bier trinkt.

Auch kann man hinter *wie* eine Sprechpause einlegen. Deswegen würde ich ein zweites Komma an dieser Stelle nicht als völlig falsch einstufen. Ich würde aber davon abraten, da es m. E. keine Leseerleichterung bringt, sondern eher stört.

Answer (score 5):

Richtig wäre:

> Das ist, wie wenn man zu viel Bier trinkt.

Allerdings ist das kein schöner Satzbau. Gesprochen kann man es gut und gerne verwenden, aber da sind dann die Kommata egal.

> Das ist, als hätte man zu viel Bier getrunken.

Wäre meiner Meinung nach besser.