# Die Verwendung von "obwohl nachdem"

Tags: punctuation

> Obwohl nachdem er über den neuen Audi seines Bruders erfahren hat, er
>   ihren Eltern darüber nicht mitteilte.

Kann man ein Komma nach der Konjunktion *obwohl* setzen, um den Satz besser lesen zu können?

Comment: Der Satz ist ohnehin grammatisch falsch. Mir ist auch nicht klar, was er aussagen soll. Welcher ist der Hauptsatz? (Erinnerung: V2)

Comment: Der Satz *könnte* lauten "Obwohl - Nachdem er vom neuen Audi seines Bruders erfahren hat, hat er ihren Eltern darüber nichts mitgeteilt". Das hat zumindestens einen hohen Wiederverwendungsgrad an Wörtern. Funktioniert allerdings nur im Kontext, wenn z.B. vorher käme "Er bespricht alles mit ihren Eltern". Keine Ahnung, ob das gemeint war.

Comment: Wahrscheinlich ein Duplikat von [Komma in: “das ist wie wenn”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/21935/2594)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Der Satz ist mehr oder weniger sinnbefreit.

> *Nachdem er über den Audi seines Bruders erfahren hat, teilte er seinen (?) Eltern nichts davon mit.*

Das ließe sich so interpretieren, dass die Erkenntnis, dass der Bruder einen neuen Audi hat, der **Auslöser** dafür war, das er die gleiche Tatsache nicht mitgeteilt hat. Lassen wir die Kausalität mal aus dem Spiel, ist der Satz zwar grammatikalisch richtig, klingt aber relativ seltsam.

> *Obwohl er über den Audi seines Bruders erfahren hat, teilte er seinen (?) Eltern nichts davon mit.*

Das macht wieder Sinn (was Thomas ja schon korrekt dargestellt hat)...

Answer (score 1):

Wenn das "Obwohl" einen eigenständigen Gedanken darstellen soll, im Sinne von "Obwohl... lass mich nachdenken... nachdem usw.", dann könnte das Komma an dieser Stelle zu einer sinnvollen Gedankenpause führen. Wenn das "Obwohl" aber zu dem Satz selbst gehören soll, kommt dort kein Komma hin.

Nebenbei angemerkt: Es ist nicht "darüber ... mitteilen", sondern "davon ... mitteilen".

Der Satz wird dadurch aber sicherlich nicht lesbarer!

Wenn es bei deiner Frage aber darum geht, wie man den Satz lesbar machen kann, hilft dir nur eine komplette Umformulierung. Beispielsweise

> Obwohl er vom neuen Audi seines Bruders erfahren hat, teilte er ihren Eltern nichts davon mit.

Das "nachdem" ist überflüssig, denn die zeitliche Abfolge ist ja implizit angegeben. Man kann ja immer nur von etwas berichten, *nachdem* man davon erfahren hat. Umgekehrt geht's ja nicht.

Comment: Die "Gedankenpause" wäre mit einem "Gedankenstrich" [sic] besser und grammatikalisch richtiger ausgedrückt als mit einem Komma. Damit sind auch so gruslige Sätze mit zwei Konjunktionen gleichzeitig (zur Not) möglich.

Answer (score 0):

In Sachen bester Lesbarkeit würde ich es so formulieren:

> Obwohl er vom neuen Audi seines Bruders wusste, teilte er den Eltern nichts
>   davon mit.

`wusste` ggfs. durch `erfahren hatte` ersetzen.